# Call UserControl's listview's button click event from UserControl's Parent

Tags: wpf, listview, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have three user controls.

**User control 1**

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Gramercy"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="wpfapplication.UCManageQALibrary"
    x:Name="UserControl"
    d:DesignWidth="774" d:DesignHeight="529.723">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid>
            <Button Content="List QA" x:Name="btnSearchQAStructure" Click="Button_Click_1" />
            <Button Content="Add New QA" x:Name="btnAddNewQAStructure"  Click="Button_Click" /> 

            <local:UCSearchQALibrary x:Name="searchQALibrary" Visibility="Visible"/>
                    <local:AddNewQA x:Name="addQALibrary" Visibility="Hidden"/>         


        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**User Control 2**

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="wpfapplication.AddNewQA"
    x:Name="UserControl"
    d:DesignWidth="1280" d:DesignHeight="1024">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid>
        <Label x:name="Label1" Content="" />

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and **User Control 3**

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="wpfapplication.UCSearchQALibrary"
    x:Name="UserControl"
    d:DesignWidth="758" d:DesignHeight="486.905">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
        <GroupBox Header="Question and Answer Master Library" >                     
        <Grid Margin="8">
            <WrapPanel Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

            <ListView Margin="4,10,0,10" x:Name="lvQA"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AlternationCount="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="420">
                            <ListView.View>
                                <GridView>
                                    <GridViewColumn >
                                        <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Label Content="Q &amp; A Search Result : " FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,4,0,4"/>
                                            </DataTemplate>                                            
                                        </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel>
                                                    <Button Content="{Binding  Path=QuestionText}" Margin="4,10,8,4" Style="{StaticResource HyperlinkLikeButton}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=QuestionID}" />
                                                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="4,0,4,4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"><Run Text="{Binding Path=AnswerText}"/></TextBlock>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn>
                                </GridView>
                            </ListView.View>                            
                        </ListView>
                    </WrapPanel>
        </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

User control 2 is used to add a new question answer, user control 3 is provide list of already created question answer. User control 1 has both user control 2 and 3. At a time either user control 2 or 3 is visible.In User control 1, on click of the List QA button user control 3 is visible and user control 2 is invisible. on click of the Add New QA button user control 2 is visible and user control 3 is invisible.

Now, In user control 3, I have a button associates with each row of the listview. On tapping/click of that button, I need a functionality to make user control 2 visible and bind the label inside user control 2 with the specific content.

I had tried with routed events.

In user control 3 I had added...

```
        public static readonly RoutedEvent AddClickEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("AddClick", RoutingStrategy.Direct, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(Button));

        public event RoutedEventHandler AddClick
        {
            add { AddHandler(AddClickEvent, value); }
            remove { RemoveHandler(AddClickEvent, value); }
        }

        void RaiseAddClickEvent()
        {
            RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(UCSearchQALibrary.AddClickEvent);
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.
            //Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadStartingPoint));
            //newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            //newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
            //newWindowThread.Start();    
            RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(AddClickEvent));
        }
```

and in User control 1 I added...

```
local:UCSearchQALibrary.AddClick="dCB_Props_AddClick"

private void dCB_Props_AddClick(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show("This Works");
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a event the is routed to the usercontrol1. 
But the better way would be to create a viewmodel (you can also use one for all 3 usercontrols).

So you create a 2 Properties in the Viewmodel with type the type Visibility and bind usercontrol1 and 2 to them. (binding is in usercontrol1).

Comment: I do not want to use view model, I am not expert in it.

Comment: So you create for each Button that fires currently a Click event a Command in a ViewModel. Apply the same Viewmodel instance to all 3 Usercontrols (just create a new instance in ctor of Usercontrol1 and pass it to 2 and 3). Set the Viewmodel to the datacontext. Now create a binding in the xaml to the commands and properties defined in the viewmodel. as example the commands to the buttons and the visibiltyproperties to usercontrol1 and 2. You won t have any code in backgroud